# How to find string which contains two numbers with a character between them

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to find a pattern which contains two positive integer number having a % or - character between them in a string. Let consider a string "Приветственный_3%5" Here we can see from the string two number 3 and 5 having a % sign between them. I want to find string having a portion of two number with a '%' or '-' sign between them.

Comment: Are your "decimal" numbers of type `int` or `decimal`? And, are they necessarily non-negative?

Comment: If you just want to check for "unsigned integer + separator + unsigned integer", I'd expect some regex like `\d[%-]\d`

Comment: It will be positive int, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for this. And you can even extract the integer values with Regex:

```
var input = "Приветственный_32%50";
var searchPattern = @"(\d+)[%-](\d+)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, searchPattern);

if (matches.Count == 1) {

    // A single occurence of this pattern has been found in the input string.
    // We can extract the numbers from the Groups of this Match.
    // Group 0 is the entire match, groups 1 and 2 are the groups we captured with the parentheses
    var firstNumber = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
    var secondNumber = matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Regex pattern explanation:

```
(\d+) ==> matches one or more digits and captures it in a group with the parentheses.
[%-]  ==> matches a single % or - character
(\d+) ==> matches one or more digits and captures it in a group with the parentheses.
```

Answer (score 0):

create a simple function that follows those steps:

1. loop throw the whole text since you want to check all
2. if current char is a digit get the full number for example 123
   you will need to  extract all before passing to stage 3.
3. if % or - is the next char after the number and next char is digit
4. extract the second number